# How frequently should you cite a paper in a section that summarizes the paper?

Tags: citations

If you are writing a summary or analysis of a paper in a section specifically devoted to it, and make it clear you are referring to that paper throughout the section, where and how frequently should you cite the paper? Should you cite only when presenting key results despite making it clear that that paper is being referenced or also when presenting more general information?